# Definition of spinor

Tags: physics, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

In most physics books, spinors are sometimes defined in an adhoc way. From my understanding, a spinor transforms under the spin group. But I'd like to know the precise detail of the definition. Can someone point me in the right direction to understand this topic in the context of mathematical details of spinors used in physics?

Comment: Did you check out the Penrose's "Spinors and Space-Time" [two-volume set](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Penrose+Spinors)?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'll check this out.

Comment: The canonical reference for this is _Spin Geometry_ by Michelsohn & Lawson.

Answer (score 5):

Using clifford algebra, rotations of vectors can be represented using double-sided multiplication by a spinor*.  That is, let $\psi$ be a spinor and $a$ be a vector, then $a'$ is the rotated vector, given by

$$a' = \psi a \psi^{-1}$$

The spinors in any given space can be constructed by a pair of sequential reflections.  And you can see that if you apply another rotation that is associated with a spinor $\phi$, then we have

$$a'' = \phi \psi a \psi^{-1} \phi^{-1}$$

So while $a$ continues to transform in a double-sided (bilinear) fashion, $\psi \to \psi' = \phi \psi$, transforming in a single-sided way.

Odds are you're already familiar with spinors on a practical level. The clifford algebra for a 2d real vector space has spinors that are isomorphic to complex numbers.  For 3d, the spinors are isomorphic to quaternions.  In applications to physics, this gives an interpretation of the Pauli algebra as merely that of rotations in 3d space--in this sense, the Pauli matrices represent basis vectors, and their products help form spinors.  The same can be said of the Dirac algebra with respect to spacetime.

(*If you like, I can elaborate on the construction with proves this.  It involves taking a sequence of two reflections, so I assure you this double-sided stuff for rotations doesn't come out of thin air.)

Comment: Good, I'm familiar with this construction. Talking about quaternions (for simplicity) when you say that $\psi$ is a spinor and $a$ a vector you mean that $\psi$ is written in the form $\psi_0+\psi_1\mathbf{n}$ where $n^2=-1$ and $a$ has zero scalar part; $a=a_1\mathbf{n'}$ right? So, by mapping the quaternions to $SU(2)$ can we say that a 3d spinor is an element of $SU(2)$? Now, in physics we usually require objects that additionally transform under the Lorentz group, do we require then that the spinors are elements of the double cover of the Lorentz group? How can this construction..

Comment: ..be extended to obtain these objects?

Comment: @Barefeg Yes, you have the details for the quaternion example right. I'm not sure we can go so far to say that 3d spinors *are* members of $SU(2)$ or are merely as a whole isomorphic to $SU(2)$. This is a mathematical subtlety that is a little beyond me. The double-reflection construction I described is equally applicable to a mixed-signature space such as Minkowski spacetime, and it generates spinors with 3 additional degrees of freedom (compared to quaternions) for the Lorentz boosts.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said that the 3d spinors are a representation of $SU(2)$, but I'm also not sure about this subtlety.

Comment: AFAIK, elements of $\mathrm{Spin}$ groups are not called spinors. Sorry I’m too late.